# TextFormField with round edges and labeltext

Tags: flutter

I would like to use a TextFormField with round edges and a labeltext where the labeltext stays inside the textfield as it does with no round edges. Is this possible?

TextFormField + No Round Edges + Labeltext:

[image]

TextFormField + Round Edges + Labeltext:

[image]

Comment: I already did this to achieve what you can see in the second screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. I have to use UnderlineInputBorder instead of OutlineInputBorder.